# QuickBlox Chat. Send custom data with message

Tags: quickblox

I successfully can send and receive messages with my JS implementation of QuickBlox Chat SDK. But I can't add custom data to any message.

```
      QB.chat.send(opponentId, {
        type: 'chat',
        custom: 'doesnt_work',
        body: currentMessage,
        extension: {
          save_to_history: 1,
        }
      });
```

Since this are 1-1 chat I didn't create a dialog. Dialog automatically created after first message sent.

Documentation telling me that this should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer by myself. Maybe this will be useful for somebody. Correct format:

```
  QB.chat.send(opponentId, {
    type: 'chat',
    body: currentMessage,
    extension: {
      save_to_history: 1,
      custom: 'it works'
    }
  });
```